# HP ProLiant ML350 G6 RAID 1 disk compatibility

Tags: storage, hp, hp-proliant, hard-drive, hp-smart-array

We are running an HP ProLiant ML350 with a RAID 1 set up on two identical 300GB 6G SAS 10K rpm SFF (2.5-inch) Dual Port Enterprise HDDs and a third acting as a "hot spare" - HP part # HPQ-507127-S21. Some time later we ordered two more of the same HPQ-507127-S21 HDDs to use in case of a need.

Recently one of the RAID HDDs has failed, the "hot spare" kicking in as expected. From what we understand if the faulty disk is replaced by a new one that is same (including size and model) the system will automatically rebuild the RAID array and the "hot spare" will return to act as a spare.

That's all good, but here's our worry:

We have noticed that the HP Model # on the 3 disks originally installed and the 2 replacement ones does not match. We still have the original invoices when the purchase was made and the part number indicated on both is the same HPQ-507127-S21. However, the 3 disks that are installed have a model # EG0300FAWHV while the two spares are model # EG0300FBLSE.

Searching on HP's PartSurfer website and checking the HP Hard Drive Model Number Matrix just added to the confusion.

What we would like to know is if the disks we have are indeed compatible and can be used in a RAID 1 setup with the old ones or there could be problems?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It won't matter. Carry on and don't think about it again. The drives will work.**

The HP Spare Part and/or Option Part numbers are what you should care about.

HP sources hard drives from several manufacturers, so you'll see a potential for different product numbers within a particular line.

An example of a 6-disk carry comprised of 900GB drives:

```
# hpssacli ctrl all show config

Smart Array P420i in Slot 0 (Embedded)    (sn: 001438026561E80)    

      physicaldrive 1I:2:1 (port 1I:box 2:bay 1, SAS, 900.1 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:2:2 (port 1I:box 2:bay 2, SAS, 900.1 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:2:3 (port 1I:box 2:bay 3, SAS, 900.1 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:2:4 (port 1I:box 2:bay 4, SAS, 900.1 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 2I:2:5 (port 2I:box 2:bay 5, SAS, 900.1 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 2I:2:6 (port 2I:box 2:bay 6, SAS, 900.1 GB, OK)
```

But looking at the HP model numbers reveals three different types of drives under the same Option Part #:

```
# hpssacli ctrl all show config detail | grep Model
         Model: HP      EG0900FBVFQ
         Model: HP      EG0900FBLSK
         Model: HP      EG0900FBLSK
         Model: HP      EG0900FBVFQ
         Model: HP      EG0900FBVFQ
         Model: HP      EG0900FCSPN
```

Answer (score 0):

EG0300FBLSE has spare part number 507284-001
EG0300FAWHV has same spare part number 507284-001
So if they have same spare part they are inter-replaceable.
I use this table for such tasks:
http://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=5177957&ac.admitted=1407853681022.876444892.492883150&docId=emr_na-c00305257-396&docLocale=en_US